# Write XML without CData

Tags: c#, xml

I want to write XML, and the output is below part in XML like ..`<abc><![CDATA[stackoverflow]]></abc>..`

```
[XmlIgnore]    
public string abc { get; set; }

[XmlElement("abc")]
public System.Xml.XmlCDataSection abc_NoCDATA
{
    get
    {
        return new System.Xml.XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(abc);
    }
    set
    {
        abc = value.Value;
    }
}
```

How can I write XML without `CDATA`?

Comment: Isn't returning a string instead of a XmlCDataSection enough ? (or, given your example, remove everything except the abc property definition). Anyway, to me it seems a stretch to use XmlSerialization to create xmls this way, but this is a personal opinion. I would use XmlTextWriter, XmlDocument or XDocument directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're explicitly returning an `XmlCDataSection`, this doesn't make sense if you don't want one.

Simply make `abc` the actual `XmlElement` that you output. This should be suffice:

```
[XmlElement("abc")]
public string abc { get; set; }
```

If you want more control, consider using [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) or [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) classes directly to create your XML Document from the start, rather than serialization.